# How to find value of "m" and "c" in these type of formula.? (formula : "Y = mxzw + c" )

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have 4 variables. let's take X, Y, Z, and W as variables. then the formula will be `y = m*x*z*w + c`. how to find the value of m and c in these formula

I have checked linear relationships with two variables. but I want to find it with variables together. I tried it with Weka software.

Comment: Are you referring to string parsing? Or do you want an algorithm for computing `m` and `c`, given `x, y, z, w`? For the latter you just need to sets of points `{x, y, z, w}`.

Comment: @a_guest I want an algorithm to compute m and c for given x, y, z, and w. what is the way we can do it? please help me

Comment: This is normal linear regression, just that your independent variable is `x*z*w`. Just calculate it beforehand and then apply linear regression.

Comment: @Samith This is a system of linear equations in `m` and `c`. Lots of software exists for solving it (e.g. `numpy.solve`) but you can also calculate it directly yourself (using a substitution `u = x*z*w` it becomes clearer).